# Seeking shapefile of traffic lights with time sequence information anywhere in world?

Tags: shapefile, data

I am looking for a shapefile of traffic lights that contains the time sequence information. As in how many seconds the green, red and yellow lights are on.

It could be a point layer of street lights of any city, district etc in the world. The idea is that it will contain attribute information that describes the sequence of each traffic light.

Comment: Can you expand on this question? For what location? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you be more specific?:
Are you looking for a shape file which contains the points representing traffic lights of a specific city (county, country)? or
Are you looking for an advice for how to build a shape file which will contain the information about traffic lights?

Comment: Location is less important, i'm looking to research a model based on it.

Comment: I seriously doubt you'll find such data. That's a signal programming level of information, and not only does it vary by location, it can vary both by the individual light and time of day. It can also be adjusted, sometimes dynamically. You might be able to get this kind of data from a traffic modeling software format, or at least test/example cases or a way to enter the info on your own. There are also standards out there (like [AASHTO](http://scote.transportation.org/Documents/2008TrafficSignalTimingManual.pdf)) with guidelines, but I think *minimum* yellow is the only *fixed* number.

Comment: A place to consider posting for any data questions is the [opendata.se] (Beta) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood you want to build the shape from zero, so it means that you do not have nothing just the need: "A shape who represents a traffic lights which contains the information about time sequence". In that case is simple, just make a field survey and obtain all the points of the traffic lights. After that you need to assign to all points the information as a field in the respective database, something like this.....
[image]